# How to implement LiveBlogPosting schema?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, search-results, articles

My website is using the `LiveBlogPosting` Schema for the iPhoneX event, but Google Search results are not showing the `Live Red Label` for it.

The same event is updated by Verge using `LiveBlogPosting` Schema:

`https://live.theverge.com/apple-live-blog-2017-iphone-8-event/`

Google Search results show the `Live Red Label`.

I haven't been able to get a clear idea of where the problem is. Why is the `Live Red label` shown for the second site, but not for mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to contact [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/live-coverage) first (Click Express Interest Button at the end of article), to get approval, because fake news sites are everywhere. And if anybody just add live blog schema and Google show it the live label without checking the site quality and past activity, then Google will lose it's trust from many people.

Google already [pre-approve many quality news](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/UMFfemnynCg) sites like The Guardian, Washington Post, The Telegraph, so may be theverge is also part of that. But as I said they no longer show red lable to other sites who use same markup, because many of them are misusing it.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. But we have already applied before 3 days. May I know how many days it takes to get approval?

Comment: I don't know because I have never apply for that :)